# Tomcat assets fail to load over Apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, ssl, tomcat, tomcat8, apache2.4

Accessing my `tomcat` webapp over SSL (https) has been working for years, but recently something strange started happening, possibly related to using docker container `tomcat:8-jdk8` (which is `v 8.5.75`) instead of `tomcat:8.5.41-jdk8` (which is no longer available). When I try to access my tomcat app through Apache's reverse proxy, over SSL (https://example.com/myapp), the main wire framework HTML page loads, but all of the `js` and `css` assets get `404`s because they are missing the app dir in the base url, so nothing visible actually loads on the page. For example, the html requests https://example.com/assets/ex.js instead of https://example.com/myapp/assets/ex.js (note `myapp/`).

However, I can access the app and everything is working 100% when accessed without Apache/SSL (http://example.com:8080/myapp).

Most strange of all, if I access the app without SSL (http://example.com:8080/myapp), and then in the same tab, change the url to the SSL path (https://example.com/myapp), then everything loads fine and functions properly. At that point, I can even `Empty Cache and Hard Reload`, and everything still loads fine over SSL. I checked the headers of all network requests, and everything is loading over SSL. This same behavior occurs in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. However, in Chrome and Safari, if I visit any other website in that tab and then try to load my app over SSL, it fails; in Firefox, the same tab will keep loading my app regardless of interceding website visits.

The Apache config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername example.com

    ##  The following email address is setup in /etc/postfix/localusers
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    UseCanonicalName On

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]
    ##  R=redirect, QSA=keep any query string, L=last rule to evaluate, stop.
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    Servername example.com
    UseCanonicalName On

    ProxyPass        /myapp http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/
    ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca.crt
    SSLVerifyDepth 2

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example_ssl-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example_ssl-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The tomcat config is [the default config](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/8.5.x/conf/server.xml) that comes in the tomcat docker container. I do not have a `META-INF/` directory in my project.

`Question 1`: why does tomcat provide the correct URLs over Apache/SSL only *after* the browser first visits tomcat directly without Apache/SSL?

`Question 2`: How can I get this app to load over SSL all the time (by always including the app name in the base url)?

Comment: If your _tomcat_ app provides the wrong URLs (e.g. http instead of https), we'd need a [mcve] for the tomcat side. Just the httpd configuration would not help.

Comment: @OlafKock Thanks, the tomcat container is all default configuration from the image.

Comment: try to remove the last / in ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse

Comment: @Juraj That fixed it, but I don't understand why that resulted in the behavior I described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source and target paths in your redirects are inconsistent. Remove the last / in the target path.

```
    ProxyPass        /myapp http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp
    ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp
```

The mapping with moreover / caused a double // in the path, which I guess caused problems down the road with processing the path in generation of the page.